# Message sent to deallocated instance when using NSOperationQueue with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am doing an asynchronous download operation using NSOperationQueue and NSOperation. The process is initiated in app delegate when the app loads.
Here is the code

```
for(Campaign *cmp in campaigns)
{
  DownloadOperation *operation = [[DownloadOperation alloc] initWithCamapign:cmp];
  [self.downloadQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

After running for a while the app crashes sending message

> [Downloadoperation retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Download operation extends NSOperation

> DownloadOperation : NSOperation

Download queue is declared in appdelagate as follows

```
NSOperationQueue *downloadQueue;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSOperationQueue *downloadQueue;
```

I am using ARC. How can I tell the compiler that the object should not be released?

> **Additions :** I have debugged the app for a while. I would like to share what I found. The class DownloadOperation is implementing a
>   delagate. The delegate basically receives the result of an HTTP
>   operation. The exception is generated when the class that handles the
>   HTTP requests tries to post the response back to the DownloadOperation
>   class. At that time when it calls

```
[self.delegate didLoadPage:pageNumber withResults:results]
```

> delegate which is the DownloadOperation class is released i guess?

Comment: `downloadQueue` should be accessed as `self.downloadQueue` or `_downloadQueue`.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo . I updated the code.

Comment: >[Downloadoperation retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
How it is possible to send 'retain' message in ARC environment?

Comment: Use Zombie or Exception Breakpoint and tell us on which line exactly you are getting this error?

Comment: IS THAT A `for loop` STARTS WITH `F`?

Comment: Did you subclass do anything to 'addOperation:'?

Comment: @DineshRaja its a typo.

Comment: please clarify: in `[self.delegate didLoadPage:pageNumber withResults:results]` what is `self` and what is `self.delegate`. The DownloadOperation CANNOT be the delegate, as you do not set any in the for loop.  Another typo: `initWithCamapign `, and a delegate message should have the signature like `delagotor:willMessageSomethingWith:`